# MultipeerConnectivity can't invite peer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, appkit

I am trying to make an ios app and an osx app communicate between each other. Everything is good until the "invite peer" part. I got the errors bellow:

```
2022-07-18 17:45:10.066594+0800 iRemoteMac[42755:5561655] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C6:1] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]
2022-07-18 17:45:10.067320+0800 iRemoteMac[42755:5558565] [MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser] PeerConnection connectedHandler (advertiser side) - error [Unable to connect].
2022-07-18 17:45:10.067366+0800 iRemoteMac[42755:5558565] [MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser] PeerConnection connectedHandler remoteServiceName is nil.
2022-07-18 17:45:20.050295+0800 iRemoteMac[42755:5562197] [MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser] Data from peer [My Dev,721645DB] received with error Connection closed.
```

Any ideas on what causes this error? I don't see where the remoteServiceName is.

thanks

Answer (score -2):

Well, I didn't set MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate right, that's why I can't invite peer, but sometimes I still get this error though the connection can be set.

Comment: You didn't provide source code of your initial issue so this answer is only useful for yourself and no one else.